# intersection of two files according to the first column

Tags: shell, text-processing, scripting, columns, join

I have two files
in  file A, there are sequence_numbers
in the other file B, there are many columns, and the first column is sequnce numbers,
I want to get a files with all the lines in the B with the sequence numbers which are in the A
how can I achieve this?
thanks

like
file A

```
1
3
8
9
20
```

file B

```
1 kfjk 3243424
2 fkdkf 23543592
3 iefjk 21493402
7 dlafdl 23435231
8 kfkdlkf 309834
```

Comment: Better provide sample input & output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `join (1)`, I guess:

> For  each  pair of input lines with identical join fields, write a
>   line
>          to standard output.  The default join field is the first, delimited  by
>          whitespace.   When FILE1 or FILE2 (not both) is -, read standard input.

```
[0 1075 12:50:10] ~/temp/sx % join A B
1 kfjk 3243424
3 iefjk 21493402
8 kfkdlkf 309834
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
```

OK, so apparently you need to combine this with `sort (1)` to sort by alpha value (not numerical value, so 20 < 3)

`join <(sort A) <(sort B)` works for me, but that looks weird and might be a zsh extension. There's no harm in doing

```
sort A > A.tmp; sort B > B.tmp; join A.tmp B.tmp
```

(As usual, check the man pages for pitfalls.)

Comment: Process substitution (`join <(sort A) <(sort B)`) works just fine in bash :-)